# How to get all the values of a particular key in a class, using Parse?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, key

How can I get all the values of a particular key, when I specify the class using the Parse framework. I've tried the following code, but it is not and ideal solution because for some odd reason it only retrieves objects every other try. How can I achieve this using Swift and the Parse framework.

`currentScreen` is the variable that contains which class name to query.

```
var messageDisplay = PFQuery(className:currentScreen)
messageDisplay.selectKeys(["userPost"])
messageDisplay.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        println("Type message \(groupConversation)")
        for object in objects {
            var textObject = object["userPost"] as String
            groupConversation.append(textObject)

        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? Put it in an array?

Comment: @soulshined yes, I am trying to put it into an array